# No InvokeEvent fired from button ( MS UI Automation Framework )

Tags: c#, user-interface, frameworks, automation

I have a little application with a flowlayout ( contains a second flowlayout with a few components and beside the second flowlayout a single close button ).

Here a Screen from Spy++: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UKy0.png

Yet i want to add a EventHandler to check the Invoke from the Close Button (last one in the screenshot). But i don't get any events from the button and i have no clue why...

Code to start and find the application:

```
Process p = Process.Start("..\\..\\..\\CSharpCaA\\bin\\Release\\dotnetCaA.exe");
AutomationElement form = AutomationElement.FromHandle(p.MainWindowHandle);
```

After i got the right Form i´m going to search for the close button:

```
AutomationElement close = form.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "close"));
```

to this point everything is fine, i have the right form and the right button ( i testet both ), so i'm going to add the EventHandler for the InvokeEvent:

```
Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent, close,
TreeScope.Element, new AutomationEventHandler(close_event));
```

My close_event method:

```
    private void close_event(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
    {
        AutomationElement senderElement = sender as AutomationElement;
        // a console writeline and other stuff            
    }
```

So I'm going to click the button and...nothing happens ! No Event fired from the close button and my close_event method wasn't called.

Somebody a idea why ? And first i thought something is wrong with my close_event but if i write something like this:

```
     Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent,
     AutomationElement.RootElement, TreeScope.Descendants, close_event);
```

i'm getting events, but from the forms and not from the components.
i tried everything, to start the form in a new thread, to create the Eventhandler in a new thread bot nothing helped. and i don't see a reason why it is not working.

**Any ideas ?**

thanks

Comment: Just some ideas: Can you call the invoke from Spy++? When you click the button manually, do you see the event fire in Spy++? Did you try the Inspect.exe Tool as well? Can you handle invokes on other buttons, that don't close the form. Maybe the form is destructed before anything happens?

Comment: do you mean the message log in spy++ of a window ? tried it today and cant see any logs there, so this could mean that no events are fired ? than i'm curious why. tested it also with our buttons from my applications, same result